# JavaScript RegExp doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Why these return `null` :

```
var str="Is this all abc bbb c is";
var patt1=/is(?=bbb)/;

var str="Is this all abc bbb c is";
var patt1=/is(?=bbb)/;

var str="Is this all there is";
var patt1=/is(?=all)/; // <------ (?=all) vs (? =all)
```

but this returns `is` :

```
var str="Is this all there is";
var patt1=/is(?= all)/;
```

?

Comment: sorry, I messed the look-behind and look-ahead patterns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?=...)
```

is the regex "look-ahead" function, so here is what your regular expressions mean:

```
/is(?=bbb)/ //look for isbbb and return is
/is(?=all)/ //look for isall and return is
```

Both of those do not exist in your string, so you get no matches.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your regular expression `/is(?=bbb)/`. Imagine a little [caret](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28computers%29) at the beginning of your expression (a caret is that blinking line between letters which shows where your text cursor is - it's behind the letter it's pointing to):

```
is(?=bbb)
^
```

We look for a small `i` in your string. We find one in the word `this`. The caret shifts:

```
is(?=bbb)
 ^
```

Is the next letter an `s`? It sure is. The caret shift again:

```
is(?=bbb)
  ^
```

Now something interesting happens. Now we check if the next letter is `b`. However even if we find it we don't advance the caret.

If we match the subexpression `bbb` only then does the caret advance to the character after the matching parenthesis (however the text matched by the subexpression isn't included in the matched string):

```
id(?=bbb)
         ^
```

Unfortunately no where in your string is `is` being followed by `bbb`. That's why you're getting `null`.